# Best practice for attempting to edit an item that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have this controller function:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    //get user from id
    var user = _adminRepository.GetUser(id);

    return View(user);
}
```

This currently gives me an error on my view page if I attempt to edit an item with an id of 100, when there is no user with an id of 100 in the database.

What's the best practice for handling this? Send them to a Create page, or show a friendly error message? Should that redirect functionality be within the controller function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would display a friendly error message telling them that the user had been removed and provide a link to the Create User page if they want to recreate the user.

I'm against redirecting the user anywhere they didn't originally intend to go, so automatically redirecting them to the Create User screen when they expected to go to the Edit User screen (I'm assuming they're separate) is not the most user friendly solution.

Comment: Agreed - much more helpful than a 404!

Answer (score 6):

IMO it should raise a 404 error. After all the user is requesting a resource that does not exist, much like a regular web page.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing on the site should *link to this page* (as it doesn't exist), therefore the only way to get here is manual. Should be a 404.

Comment: @RPM1984 - The idea is that I have a grid of users, each with an Edit button. We ran into some issues where a user was deleted by someone, then someone else clicked the Edit button on the grid page they had open for a while, causing an error.

Comment: @Steven: In that case you should consider periodically updating the grid on the client side to avoid the problem entirely. The root of all evil here seems to be an outdated grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should redirect them to Create Page with an Extra information as to why they are redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply to @RPM1984, i think your problem is with the Update Action since you already have the view opened. i suggest you do redirect to friendly error page saying "The user you are trying to update doesn't exist." when you click save then find out the user isn't there anymore. With a link to go back to your grid and see the latest set of users.

This page would be helpful also for some users might try to access the url directly instead of using your grid..

i.e.

some may type

http://mysite.com/users/edit/215215132

where 215215132 is your userId.

i'm just assuming this is how you do it.